# How to get the upper Child in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the upper child ID when the current user is equal to user ID in the child

and i have this

could you help me ?

```
fun loadOwnOffer() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (data in snapshot.children) {

                val model = data.getValue(OffersModelClass::class.java)

                val userID: String = model?.userID.toString()

                if (userID == firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid) {

                    Log.d("Getting User ID", userID)
                    
                }

            }
        }
}
```

[image: See The Image]

Comment: If I correctly get what you want to achieve, data.getKey() should contain the value you need: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#getkey

Comment: How is `databaseReference` initialized?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the offers for a specific UID, you can do that with a query:

```
fun loadOwnOffer() {
    asser(Firebase.auth.currentUser != null) { "Cannot load offer without active user" }
    val myUid = Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid
    val database = Firebase.database
    val offersRef = database.getReference("offers")
    val myOffersQuery = offers.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(myUid)

    myOffersQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (data in snapshot.children) {
                 ...
```